# GWT Request Factory create ValueProxy from object

Tags: servlets, gwt, proxy, requestfactory

**GWT Request Factory : create ValueProxy instance from bean**

I'm looking for a way to convert beans to corresponding ValueProxy on server side without using Request Factory.

MyBean --> MyBeanProxy

Context : i call my service from an other servlet (using ServiceLocator), my  service returns beans , i need to convert those objects to corresponding Proxies , serialize them with AutoBean and send them to client. Client side is heavily linked to those value Proxies, lot of work if i need to implement all that ...

As far as my bean supposed to correspond to implementation of the Proxy's interface I can't figure out why no solution are available in RF framework to convert beans to proxy.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize using AutoBean? If you're going to deserialize using AutoBean, then the input can be any JSON object with properties of the appropriate name and value type, so you can serialize on the server side the way you want: Jackson, GSON, AutoBean, etc.

Comment: You mean serialize MyBean and deserialize as MyBeanProxy ? My first concern is to be able to deserialize as Proxy objects on the client side. Using AutoBean , jackson , Gson or whatever ...

Comment: Do you want a fully functional proxy? Or just an object that happens to implement the interface?

Comment: So far object which implement the interface seems to work properly when i deserialize as proxy object on client side...  What advantage can i get from a fully functional proxy ??  To be honest i really care about getting a Value Proxy to deserialize on client side to not have to re-write client code and gain time ...

Comment: “fully functional” as in “can be assigned to a proxy's property, or sent to the server through a RequestFactory call”

Comment: They are not "fully functional" at all , even they are unfrozen (maybe too much AC) ! I've try with AutoBean , not successful ...  What is the mechanism of the RF that transform the objects returned by service to corresponding proxy ? Request Context is the starting point but is there any way to use it without request/receiver model ?